# Could a PC consume more power from the plug if it oparates in a colder enviroment?

Tags: temperature, power-consumption, pc, graphics

I have a mining rig (computer using its processing power to calculate hashes in order to eventually be rewarded with cryptocurrency tokens.)

The program I use to mine tells me each time the power consumption of my hardware (basically only the graphics card power consumption) which is around 900 watt stable (it measures it every few seconds.)

I also have a meter which shows me the total power consumption drawing from the mains/plug.

I noted the following discrepancies (or at least I found them to be.)

While my hardware is under the same load (99% +-1%) constantly and my mining program displays the same power consumption (900 watts) independently of the outside temperature while the meter on the plug when it is a warm day shows around 980 watts consumption but at night when it is cold (I keep my rig in a shed thinking that cold would do good in terms of stability and maintaing low component temperatures while under load) the meter on the plug shows more than 1080 watt usage.

Is there something in the circuitry of the meter that could mess with measurements because of low room temperature or do electronics (be it my computer's powersupply or my graphics cards) consumer more energy while operating on low room temperatures?

Note that the mining program power draw measurements are relatively accurate because either in cold or in warm weather if I increase the power consumption of the cards it shows an increased value while the meter on the plug also shows a somewhat proportionally increased value.

EDIT: By cold weather I mean about -5 to 5 degrees C and by warm anything above 12ish degrees.

Comment: MOSFET resistance increases with temperature, as do typical resistances elsewhere in the computer. How "cold" is cold? Cold at night in the shed for me means anything below -15C.

Comment: cold about -5 to 5, warm about 10-15, is there anything I could do to remedy that effect? my target is to keep power consumption low without sacrificing on system performance.

Comment: Your OS is going to be a factor here. Is it throttling your processor? Are the fans running full tilt? I don't think the characteristics of the transistors will matter much at all.

Comment: CMOS transistors will switch faster when cold, but most of the power consumed is for charging the gates and other signal path capacitance. This doesn't change much over temperature. I suspect a secondary affect like Elliot eluded to.

Comment: @Mattman944 So it is not likely that my meter gets a little off when cold? (it's this one https://www.daraz.pk/products/uni-t-power-meter-ut230b-eu-i100952266.html)

Comment: @Elliot Alderson so running the miner the CPU is hardly used only the Graphics cards which I undervolt (both memory and GPU) I increased the hz on the memory (HBM2) by 150 Mhz and I decreased the GPU clock down to 1200Mhz (450mhz difference) fans dont ramp up in cold weather by they may get @ about 85% for a while on warm weather (1,5V fans 1A each card has 3 of those 10 cards in tota I dont think its the fans though)

Comment: I would expect power consumption to go down with CMOS and lower temp but rise with relative humidity dielectric constant between pins.

Comment: So the rig says 900W always. That is probably DC watts. The AC power meter shows anywhere from 980 to 1080 watts. That seems like reasonable efficiency. But I don't know why the input power would vary with temperature. Maybe it doesn't. Maybe the AC meter power reading has a temperature sensitivity. In any event, I think this will be difficult to resolve fully.

Answer (score 2):

Many modern CPUs and GPUs automatically scale down their clock speed and/or number of operational cores if they are too hot in order to prevent dangerous overheating. This could well be the cause of your discrepancy; if it is (which you should be able to test by monitoring your number of hashes per second in different conditions) you may need to install additional cooling.

While it is perfectly possible for either your consumption to change a little without this happening or for your meter's calibration to drift as temperature changes, I would expect both to show the opposite effect,i.e. reading higher power consumption in warmer conditions, so I don't believe this is likely to be the case.

Comment: I thought of this too. Thermal throttling could explain why power consumption would go UP when temp goes DOWN. But why does the power meter for the rig stay pegged at 900W?

Comment: no the clocks (both  GPU and GPU vram , cpu isnt used anyway during mining ) are constant on the highest level I set them to be and my hashesh are constant as well. It is just that when the room is much colder the meter on the plug shows higher consumption (the program gives the same consumption)